# Can't get HTML checkbox value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get ASP.NET checkbox value which can be user input or retrieved from database. But each time it's showing this error message

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '`value`' of `undefined` or `null` reference

My HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" data-member="IsSubGroupNecessary" data-label="" data-provider="checkbox" onchange="IsSubGroupNeeded();"/>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function IsSubGroupNeeded() {
    var Subgrp = document.getElementById('<%=myCheck.ClientID%>').checked;
    if (Subgrp == true) {
        loadgrdSubgroupItem();
    }
};
```

**Update:**
The error issue is solved.
But I want to call loadgrdSubgroupItem function when checkbox value is true whether it is user input or retrieved from database. How to do it?

Comment: `document.getElementById('myCheck')` is that worked ?

Comment: It seems that error is thrown somewhere else, can you attach debugger in browser and check where this exception is thrown ?

Comment: @Amey Deshpande it doesn't fire the error but doesn't work too.

Comment: Original Question was for ASP.NET checkbox, approved edit is now HTML checkbox.What the hell.

Comment: @mimi: re: update - if you have a follow up question [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new one :-)

Comment: @NikolaiDante Ok. Asked a new one :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rendered HTML has an id of `myCheck` so you should be able to:

```
function IsSubGroupNeeded() {
    var Subgrp = document.getElementById('myCheck').checked;
    if (Subgrp == true) {
        loadgrdSubgroupItem();
    }
};
```

Without the need for the server side call.

(I assume that you have [ClientIDMode="Static"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) on your asp.net markup)

Comment: `#` needed?I think no hash needed

Comment: Yes, I think I may have gone to jquery by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Since checkbox is not an ASP control , you can do as

```
var subgrp = document.getElementById('myCheck').checked
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the name of the control only to `getElementById` to find that element here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/crtf689s/):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function IsSubGroupNeeded() {
var Subgrp = document.getElementById('myCheck').checked;
   alert(Subgrp)

};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" data-member="IsSubGroupNecessary" data-label="" data-provider="checkbox" onchange="IsSubGroupNeeded();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
var Subgrp = <%=myCheck.Checked%>;
```

**If checkbox is HTML**

```
function IsSubGroupNeeded() {
    var Subgrp = document.getElementById('myCheck').checked;
    if (Subgrp == true) {
        loadgrdSubgroupItem();
    }
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be set on form rendering and never ever change on checkbox clicks?

Comment: OP told it is an ASP.NET checkbox, so `<%=myCheck.Checked%>;` will work perfectly.

Comment: I oppose this downvote. Can the person explain downvote?