# How to call a function in javascript when a HTML Checkbox is checked without onclick or onchange

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function when checkbox value is true whether it is user input or retrieved from database. How to do it?
My Code

```
function IsSubGroupNeeded() {
    var Subgrp = document.getElementById('myCheck').checked;

    if (Subgrp === true) {
        loadgrdSubgroupItem();
    }
};
```

From where should I call IsSubGroupNeeded function?

Comment: How is this different from your [last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312861/cant-get-html-checkbox-value-in-javascript) question?

Comment: @Tushar it worked well with "onchange" in HTML. But I want without onchange. My last question answers solved my error and someone told to ask new one.

Comment: should i give you an answer using jquery @Mimi

Comment: Though I haven't used jquery yet but It's ok  @Transformer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. for checkbox data coming from database on `document.ready` will do that for you, but for user input in an already loaded page you must go with either click or change and then check if its currently `checked`. the `if(this.checked)` will do that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //on document load 
    if ($('input#mycheck').is(':checked')) {
        //cal the function
    }
});
// you have to do a check on when user input (click)
$("input#mycheck").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //call the function
    }
});

});
```